# Font issue : Controls text cutoff in Windows 7 machine

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-xp

I have a Visual Studio 2008 Windows Application which typically has menu items,textboxes and some buttons on almost every other forms. It looks great on my development machine which is **XP SP3**.

I read my AppConfig file to set the font family and font size which is common to all forms.
For ex:  I use the **Arial 10** font to be used to be used for all controls in all the forms

But when I installed the application on **Window7**, the font looks little bit big and i can see cutoff in the some menuitems and in other controls for ex: labels.

Does this mean that the font setting on a Windows XP machine is different from the setting on a Windows 7 ??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It may not be this, but you need to be aware that font scaling on Windows 7 can work differently to Windows XP. Check that, if font scaling is in use, it's being done with the XP-compatible mechanism.

Comment: Looks like this issue is occuring because of the AutoSize property of my Winform. Its currently set as false. If i make this as true, though my problem of cutoff is solved, i get a new problem where in the control width size has grown beyond requirement

Comment: Also ... the form AutoSizeMode property has been set to AutoSizeMode.GrowandShrink